# Kubernetes execute cat in a pod from a script blocks execution

Tags: shell, kubernetes, cat

the following script works :

```
#!/bin/bash
kubectl exec -ti mypod -- bash -c "cat somefile"
```

but

```
#!/bin/bash
command="cat somefile"
kubectl exec -ti mypod -- bash -c $command
```

does not.

```
chmod +x myscript.sh
./myscript.sh
```

the prompt never returns!!!

What is wrong with the second script?
Thanks in advance,
Abdelghani

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the quotes. `command="cat somefile"` will store in the variable the string *cat somefile*.

The script should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
command="cat somefile"
kubectl exec -ti mypod -- bash -c "$command"
```

Comment: Works. Thkx Neo